# If I install xcode 6 will it replace my old Xcode and other questions too

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

If I install xcode 6 will it overwrite my Xcode 5?

Also will I still be able to publish apps using Xcode 5 if it doesn't overwrite it?

Will I be able to publish apps using Xcode 6 too?

Comment: You will have everything from before. You won't lose anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode is simply a drag & drop install, which means you can choose to replace Xcode 5 with it OR you can have Xcode 6 live side by side with Xcode 5.

Apple hasn't mandated to submit apps using Xcode 6 yet, but eventually they will, probably once Xcode 6 leaves "beta" status.

Comment: Might as well note that if you simply drag and drop the beta Xcode into your application folder it will live beside your existing Xcode installation as the name is "Xcode6-Beta3.app" and your default installation is Xcode.app.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 will still be present on the system you're using, and Xcode 6 is able to publish apps the same way as Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Dautermann is right. You can install or keep xcode 6 beside xcode 5.

You should use xcode 5 to publish app.

Comment: So that means even if I install Xcode 6, I will still be able to publish apps through Xcode 5?

Comment: Yes if you keep both installed.